# How do I update a table using a staging table to avoid inserting duplicate records?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a **main table** called `arrests` with **primary key** `arrest_key` that is currently empty. I have a **staging table** called `arrests_temp` that contains one month of data. The staging table looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/v8QGynD.png

I have the following so far:

```
UPDATE arrests 
SET arrests.arrest_key = arrests_temp.arrest_key 
FROM arrests LEFT JOIN arrests_temp 
ON arrests.arrest_key = arrests_temp.arrest_key 
WHERE arrests.arrest_key != arrests_temp.arrest_key;
    
INSERT INTO arrests (arrest_key, arrest_date, pd_cd, pd_desc, ky_cd) 
SELECT arrest_key, arrest_date, pd_cd, pd_desc, ky_cd
FROM arrests_temp 
WHERE arrest_key NOT IN (SELECT arrest_key FROM arrests);
```

I keep getting the following error:

> ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM arrests
> LEFT JOIN arrests_temp \n    ON arrests.arrest_key = arrests_temp.ar'
> at line 3")

```
[SQL: 
    UPDATE arrests 
    SET arrests.arrest_key = arrests_temp.arrest_key 
    FROM arrests LEFT JOIN arrests_temp 
    ON arrests.arrest_key = arrests_temp.arrest_key 
    WHERE arrests.arrest_key != arrests_temp.arrest_key;
    ]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MySQL and I'm executing these commands in a Python script using SQLAlchemy.

Comment: A primary key cannot be empty.  The description doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were using the SQL Server syntax but MySQL works differently

```
UPDATE arrests 
LEFT JOIN arrests_temp ON arrests.arrest_key = arrests_temp.arrest_key 
SET arrests.arrest_key = arrests_temp.arrest_key 
WHERE arrests.arrest_key != arrests_temp.arrest_key
```

Every DB engine has a somewhat different SQL syntax.

Comment: Thank you, Juergen! The person who had helped me before must have used a different DBMS.